# Is it appropriate to do a follow-up email when not applying for a specific position?

Tags: applications, follow-up

This is pretty self-explanatory- I sent in my resume and cover letter a few weeks ago and was wondering if it would be appropriate to send a follow-up email even though I was not applying for any specific position. Thanks.

Comment: I think if you're sending a resume you need to find a person who you know there, a job that's open there, a problem that needs solving there, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've heard back from them in some form or another probably not. If they were interested in hiring you they would have said something. Most likely they put your resume on file incase something opens up in the future that they think you might be a good fit for. At this point if you continue to contact them without any other reason they may start looking at it as spam which will all but guarantee you never hear from them in the future.